# Firebase Authentification and Flask

Tags: firebase, flask, firebase-authentication

I am trying Firebase to authenticate users for a website that was initially built on Flask (using the flask login workflow with a postgres DB). However, I am not sure that I have a correct understanding of what would be considered best practices when using Firebase.

I read through this [article](https://medium.com/@nschairer/flask-api-authentication-with-firebase-9affc7b64715), which I think has led me down a suboptimal path when it comes to actually managing users.

My questions are:

1. Should all the Firebase authentication be handled in the javascript?
2. If so, should I use the `request.headers` on the backend to verify the identity of the user?

Any tutorials (aside from the [Firenotes](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/app-engine) one, which I am working through) much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should all the Firebase authentication be handled in the javascript?

No, it doesn't have to be JavaScript. But in general, you'll find that most apps using one of the existing Firebase Authentication providers handle the sign-in of the user in their client-side code, with calls to the authentication server.

> If so, should I use the request.headers on the backend to verify the identity of the user?

When calling REST APIs Firebase itself passes the ID token of the authenticated user in the `Authorization` header, so that's a valid approach indeed. On the server you can then [verify that the ID token is valid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and decide what data this user has access to.